# averaging alternating lengths of data in a column in excel

Tags: excel

I have a large data file in Excel (100000 rows) broken up into 20 minute time increments, the problem is that these increments alternate between 180 rows and 120 rows. How would i be able to get an average of each of these time increments?

As I am fairly new to excel so far I have been doing this by hand because I have not had access to internet, but its both tedious and time consuming, any help would be great.
Cheers

Comment: `but its both tedious and time consuming` ... and error prone, and for these reasons you might want to look into pivot tables.  Excel pivot tables give you some database functionality in your spreadsheet and they can readily compute the averages you want.

Comment: How would you identify if the range is 180 or 120 rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `AVERAGEIF` function. For example,

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A,A1,B:B)
```

This formula will return the average of all cells in column B where the value in column A is the same, meaning if the value in column A doesn't change for 120 rows it will return the same value 120 times but then  change on the 121st row. The interval of change is immaterial. You might use conditional formatting to hide duplicates if they trouble you.

The following formula will avoid writing repetitive duplicates.

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(AVERAGEIF(A:A,A2,B:B)=INDEX(C$1:C1,MATCH(10^16,C$1:C1,1)),A2=A1),"",AVERAGEIF(A:A,A2,B:B)),AVERAGEIF(A:A,A2,B:B))
```

In order to function it needs to write "" in the cells which are to be shown blank. If you need to use the averages in further calculations please bear in mind that "" is a string, not a number. You can convert it to zero by using the SUM function. For example, if A1 = "", `=SUM(A1)` evaluates to zero.

Comment: This has me on the right track i think, il have a play around and see what i can do about the duplicates

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a solution for the duplicates.

Comment: i just put the data into a pivot table and got the reduced result, thanks for your help, saved me a lot of man hours and pain